# Type name as value?

Tags: kotlin

Can somebody point me to the documentation explaining what the following means? Especially, I'd like to know why `String` and `Int` can be used as shown.

```
val a: Unit = { _: Any -> String }(Int)
```

Initially, I had written this:

```
val a: Unit = { x: Any -> x.toString() }(Unit)
```

In both cases, I've failed to find the right documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Type name as value?

`String` and `Int` are the [companion objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) (sort of the equivalent to Java's `static`) of the `String` and `Int` classes. The name of a class is synonymous with the name of its companion object, i.e. `Int` more or less is the same as `Int.Companion`, etc.

`{ _:Any -> String }` and `{ x:Any -> x.toString() }` are both [lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax) of type `(Any) -> String.Companion` and `(Any) -> String`, but since the result of the function call is assigned to `a`, which is of type `Unit`, these functions are both inferred to return `Unit`.

Basically, after type inference:

`{ _:Any -> String }` is a `(Any) -> Unit`

`{ x:Any -> x.toString() }` is also a `(Any) -> Unit`

> This type corresponds to the `void` type in Java.
>
> <sub>[Documentation: Unit](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/index.html)</sub>

So these functions both effectively do nothing.

The first function (of type `(Any) -> Unit` takes one argument (which is unused) and returns `String.Companion`.

In this case, it is called with `Int.Companion`... but the argument is unused, so it doesn't matter.

You could have written:

```
val lambda: (Any) -> Unit = { _: Any -> String }
val a: Unit = lambda(Int)
```

The second function calls `toString` on its parameter, which is in this case `Unit`. The string representation of `Unit` [is defined as `"kotlin.Unit"`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.0/core/builtins/src/kotlin/Unit.kt#L23), but since it is assigned to `a` the function's return type is inferred to be `Unit`, so the function doesn't return anything useful.

These functions are both quite useless as they return `Unit` (i.e. `void`, nothing). What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks @Moira. I'm just trying to better understand Kotlin's type inference. Now, I get the `Companion` trick. Tricky but ok. However, I'm still a bit puzzled by the “cast” of an `(Any) -> String` value into `(Any) -> Unit`. Does this is mean a trailing `; return kotlin.Unit` (I know the syntax is wrong) is added at the end of the body of the λ?

Comment: @cuihtlauac Yep, that's basically it. It ignores the return value and returns `Unit` (or, from a Java standpoint, `Unit.INSTANCE`, since it's a singleton) instead.

Answer (score 6):

Let's break down the first line.

```
{ _: Any -> String }
```

This is a lambda. It takes one parameter, that's marked as never used by giving it the name `_`. The parameter of this type is specified as `Any`. The lambda returns `String`, which refers to the (completely empty) [`companion object` inside the `String` class](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.0/core/builtins/native/kotlin/String.kt#L24). The type of this lambda is therefore `(Any) -> String.Companion`.

```
{ _: Any -> String }(Int)
```

This lambda is invoked by the parentheses after it, passing in `Int`, which again refers to the [`companion object` inside that class](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.0/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Primitives.kt#L378) (this one isn't empty, it contains constants). This works, because of course, `Int.Companion` is a subtype of `Any`, the expected parameter type.

```
val a: Unit = { _: Any -> String }(Int)
```

Finally, the declaration of `a` with its explicit `Unit` type forces the lambda to change its inferred type from `(Any) -> String.Companion` to `(Any) -> Unit`, so it can return the expected explicit type after it's invoked.

The second line is more of the same, only simpler without the companion objects.

Comment: Thanks @zsmb13. In the second case, when passing `Unit` to the λ, am I denoting `Unit.Companion` (of type `Any`) or `kotlin.Unit` (of type `Unit`)?

Comment: [`Unit`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.0/core/builtins/src/kotlin/Unit.kt#L22) is actually a singleton `object` already, so in that case, you're referencing its single instance.

Answer (score 3):

You defined a lambda `{ _: Any -> String }` of type `(Any)-> String.Companion` and called it with the `Int.Companion` object. It always returns the `String.Companion` object. Does not make much sense. The following might be more readable:

```
val func = { _: Any -> String.Companion }
val res = func(Int.Companion)
```

Note that `Int` and `Int.Companion` are used interchangeably here (also applies for the `String` one).

Information about companion objects can be found in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects).